# Is it ethical to live a frugal/simple life?

Tags: ethics

It is generally accepted that modern consumerism has caused significant environmental problems for humanity. But on the other hand, many people, especially the poor, often have their livelihood depending on the richer to consume their product and services. For example, tourism is a major income for many countries and regions.

What are the takes of different ethical philosophy schools on consumption?

An article on this issue: https://aeon.co/ideas/why-the-simple-life-is-not-just-beautiful-it-s-necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole argument will be based on a utilitarian~ish ethical framework.
Firstly consider a situation with a pile of resources that are used to provide for people. Given unlimited resources, there will be many ways to use those to benefit a person. This isn't to say that every mod con will make your life better, just that some will. Given a fixed population, the best state of the world has everyone living in opulent luxury. However, there might be a limited amount of resources. Human utility functions are generally sub-linear in resources. Most humans would far prefer to have £1 million than a 50/50 chance between £2 million and totally destitute. Given a fixed pool of resources, it is better to spread them evenly. There are some exceptions to this in really bad circumstances. If you have 2 people stranded on a desert island, and a food supply about enough for one, it is better for one person to live and one to starve quickly, than for both to starve slowly.
So given a fixed pool of resources, neither live more frugally nor less frugally than others.

Lets bring in some more complicating factors. 
Environmental harm. There are some luxuries, like maybe private jets that harm others through emissions more than they benefit the recipient. At other times, the heat pump might be more environmentally friendly than the log fire. (I haven't done any kind of detailed analysis here, just pointing out that these cases probably exist and giving an example that look like a case on superficial mentioning).

If you buy plastic tat made in china, you are benefiting the Chinese plastic tat manufacturers. But not as much as if you gave them cash directly.

Most importantly, the pile of resources isn't fixed. Search the term "effective altruist". You can earn more money to help the needy by being an investment banker in an expensive suit than a bin man in rags. Investment banks won't hire people who come to interviews in rags. So if you have the skills to be an investment banker, its better to buy an expensive suit and apply for a job than to be a binman or whatever. 
There are also jobs that help people directly. If you are a brilliant medical researcher, penny pinching is a waste of your time and energy that could be put into work. Don't live on potatoes and gruel. Work a little more and then buy something healthy and quick. Don't work yourself to exhaustion either. In fields like research, much of the progress is made by the very best. 5 hours a day of brilliant work is better than 20 hours a day of mediocre work. Other professions that the effective altruists consider important include managing the risks of synthetic biology, nanotech and AI; Nuclear disarmament, existential risk reduction, and organizing effective charities, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning seems to  go like this

(1) If people life frugal lives, they will have less needs and desires

(2) If they have less needs and desires, there will be less money transfer from the rich to the poor.

(3) Money transfer from the rich to the poor is necessary, or at least desirable.

(4) Hence, living a frugal life ( if adopted as a general rule) would have unethical consequences.

I think premise (1) can be discussed.

Livng a frugal life does not necessarily mean having less needs or desires, but having less artificial desires.

By freeing themselves from artificial desires, people could discover their natural desires, including their desire for things that are more " natural"  ( health, sport, games, associations,  wholesome food,  intellectual enhancing, learning, good housing, etc.).

But , there is no reason to think that satisfying natural desires reduces the need for social cooperation : organic agriculture may require much more employees than industrial agriculture, this is just an example.

Comment: I bought a book today after similar consideration. :)